# ¿Como obtengo la url de una imagen con un elemento de asp.net?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo obtener el valor de toda la `url` de mi imagen seleccionada, mi código actual es el siguiente:

**Código javascript**

```
   var image= document.getElementById('<%=fileImage.ClientID%>').value;
```

**Codigo .aspx**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileImage" class="fileImagen" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
```

Actualmente puedo obtener solo el nombre del archivo con jquery.

**Codigo Jquery:**

```
var imagen = $(".fileImagen").val();
```

Pero yo necesito saber toda la ubicación del archivo.

Comment: Seria bueno que nos comentes para que lo necesitas en javascript este valor, asi te podremos ayudar mejor. Ya que no se puede obtener el path completo.

Comment: @Jose A. Fernandez lo quiero para guardar toda mi url en un campo de mi BD

Comment: Como te he comentado, por motivos de seguridad no puedes acceder al path local del archivo seleccionado (incluso utilizando la File API de Html5). Pero a tu respuesta "para guardar en la DB", Luego con dicho path no puedes hacer nada desde el servidor. ¿Pero que funcionalidad ibas a hacer con dicho campo? Ya que no lo puedes utilizar. Querias luego hacer un enlace para que el usario lo pueda abrir desde su maquina/PC? Cual era la idea "funcional" de dicho campo en la DB. Mas info de [File API de Html5](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por motivos de seguridad no es posible acceder via javascript a los path "fisico" (full path) que contiene el INPUT del tipo file.

Por esa razon es la que solamente puedes obtener con val() el nombre del archivo

NOTA: En su momento hace un par de años en IE se podia, grave! y habia un metodo en FF que podias obtenerlo. Pero no es un standard y no podras llevarlo todos los browsers

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método prop pasándole como atributo el src de tu imagen, tal que así:

```
var imagen = $(".fileImagen").prop('src');
```

Es válido con jQuery 1.6 o superior

Answer (score 0):

```
var src = document.querySelector('#fileImage').getAttribute('src');
```

ese codigo js deberia andar